Can these white parts of UI of Windows 10 and 11 be edited without a high contrast theme?
I don't want to use a high contrast theme because that is too uniform and removes transparency; I was able to use a program called SMACC to modify most of the colors that the overall color settings in Windows 10 doesn't affect, as indicated here. These seem to be the same settings accessible in only numerical terms at Registry Editor entry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors.
But there is a part of the UI that cannot be edited at that level, this white-gray part as seen in Notepad:

I know there is a way to do that, high contrast themes can do it, for example this one.
But can such changes be enabled without the high contrast mode that disables transparency etc?

I have already tried SMACC and  Classic Color Panel (now non-free), but they do nothing more than modify Registry Editor entry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors. There is also WinPalleter that looks more complicated, but I think cannot change the specific aspect I address here.

Try MicaForEveryone.

@harrymc - Can you give more detailed instruction on the very specific aspect I discuss here? Mica's options are not at all self-explanatory, beside the fact that it contains the warning that, depending on the app, the app UI could break, a thing confirmed quickly and randomly on parts of the desktop that were not concerned (the mouse pointer, for example). It has no per-color options as such, offers to extend some coloring in a way that has nothing to do with what I ask here. Managed to replace a part of normal dark in WExplorer with my blue color above, and the above with something else.

I haven't used this app, but there aren't too many such apps.

@harrymc - Ok. Should have said that first. :) I did. Strongly advise against it. I'll add to question the few apps I've tested already. I know what those do and want to. Likewise, I am curious what Mica is supposed to do.
